# Get errror JSONException: No Value For

Tags: android, json

i have a problem with json parsing code it shows error json no value for konteks lokasi which is use TAG_KONTEKS variable.
This is my code for get json response.

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //mendapatkan data dari database berupa alamat, konteks, latitude, longitude
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", Integer.toString(latPengguna)));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng", Integer.toString(lngPengguna)));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("konteks", konteksCocok));
        Log.d("lat dan lng kirim", "data: " + Integer.toString(latPengguna) + " " + Integer.toString(lngPengguna));
        Log.d("konteks kirim", "data: " + konteksCocok);
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_webservice, "POST", params);
        Log.d("data: ", json.toString());

        //menampilkan data lokasi POI
        try {
            int sukses = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if(sukses == 1) {
                POI = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POIN);
                for(int i = 0; i < POI.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = POI.getJSONObject(i);
                    int latDB = c.getInt(TAG_LAT);
                    int lngDB = c.getInt(TAG_LNG);
                    String alamat = c.getString(TAG_ALAMAT);
                    String konteks = c.getString(TAG_KONTEKS);

                    Log.d("latDB", "data: " + latDB);
                    Log.d("lngDB", "data: " + lngDB);
                    Log.d("altDB", "data: " + alamat);
                    Log.d("ktsDB", "data: " + konteks);                     
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(TAG_ALAMAT, alamat);
                    map.put(TAG_KONTEKS, konteks);
                    POIList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("JSON error", "JSON trouble");
            }
        } catch(JSONException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is my json response:

```
{
"success": 1,
"point": [
    {
        "point": {
            "konteks_lokasi": "kuliah",
            "nama_lokasi": "Teknik Perkapalan",
            "longitude": "-60",
            "latitude": "117"
        },
        "hasil": 15.811388300842
    },
    {
        "point": {
            "konteks_lokasi": "kuliah",
            "nama_lokasi": "Teknik Kimia",
            "longitude": "-80",
            "latitude": "145"
        },
        "hasil": 33.376638536557
    },
    {
        "point": {
            "konteks_lokasi": "kuliah",
            "nama_lokasi": "Teknik Arsitektur",
            "longitude": "-22",
            "latitude": "111"
        },
        "hasil": 53.009433122794
    }
]
```

}

I would be very happy if you could help me...

Comment: What is this TAG_KONTEKS ? What's the expansion for this one in your mapper(Tlds, etc whatever) ?

Comment: It's a json response tag for data konteks: private static final String TAG_KONTEKS = "konteks_lokasi";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Longitude and Latitude are strings, as they are surrounded by quotes. so you should get them with getString()

parse them like this

Your JSONArray contain another json Array so parse it like this

```
int sukses = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if(sukses == 1) {
                POI = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POIN);

                for(int i = 0; i < POI .length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = POI .getJSONObject(i);
                     JSONObject d = c.getJSONObject(0);

                    String latDB = d.getString(TAG_LAT);
                    String lngDB = d.getString(TAG_LNG);
                    String alamat = d.getString(TAG_ALAMAT);
                    String konteks = d.getString(TAG_KONTEKS);
}
```

Comment: But under c.getJSONObject shows red line which shows error 
The method getJSONObject(String) in the type JSONObject is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Comment: sorry it should be `getJSONObject("point")`, replace with this